# Adaptive cards to approve/reject a sharepoint list item and updating the same in the sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint-online, outlook, sharepoint-list

My current flow sends an email to the user when new item is added in the SharePoint list.
I want to add an actionable email message, so when the user receives the email from flow the email has to add Comment to a textbox and either 'Approve' or 'Reject', this way the line item in the SharePoint list is updated- the column 'Approval Status' = 'Approved'/'rejected' and column 'comments' = 'comments added by the mail receiver'

I'm trying to achieve so the user don't have to visit the SharePoint list but can respond directly in the email using a Actionable Message and once the user approves or rejects, the mail is updated with a new message saying 'The entry has been rejected or approved' as per the user's selection.

Can anyone has tried something similar and help me here.

Answer (score 1):

Your requirement is achievable using the OOB Approvals actions in Flow.

Turn on **Content Approval** in the list and add the "*Approval Status*", "*Approver Comments*" columns to the list view.
The process is completed by the Flow without user interaction in the SharePoint list.

Reference: [Create and test an approval workflow with Power Automate.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/modern-approvals)

Here is a sample flow for your reference:
[image]

And here is the test outcome:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. :) Actually I wanted to add few more information to the email in a tabular format. That's why was looking for doing it via Json and adaptive cards so that the rest information I can add it in the body of Send an email V2. Please suggest how can I achieve the same.

Comment: @HRY How about building a HTML Table in Send an email V2 action? See a reference here: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-create-and-format-html-table-using-microsoft-flow-and-sharepoint-online/